# Very high energy impact and frame drops on iOS

Tags: unity, performance, ios, mobile

I have created a mobile 3D game and now I am running it on an iOS device. It works well and runs at about about 25 fps. But after a while, about 2-3 minutes, it drops to 15 - 18 frames per second.

My triangle counts and batches are not very high.

[image: Render statistics]

I turned vsync off and set `Application.targetFrameRate = 1;` and only put one monster in my main scene.  It keeps dropping frame rate and the energy impact is still getting very high.

[image: Render statistics 2]

[image: Profiler]

[image: Energy impact]

Comment: Does it drop further the longer your game is running? In that case you have a memory leak. But your main usage seems to be the editor loop and should not there in case it is already a standalone build

Comment: English spell checking software is freely available. Please use it so we don't have to do so much cleanup on your posts.

Comment: Profiling on a computer usually is not a great way to determine what's causing performance issues on mobile. Functions that take less than 1ms on a decent computer might take several milliseconds on mobile. Your CPU usage looks somewhat high (46%), and it sounds like lowering the framerate isn't fixing the issue, so your problem is likely with your C# code.

Comment: @Zibelas  yes  It is likely to be a memory leak, and the memory usage increased by 2g after one minute

Comment: @Kevin Even if I disable all the canvases and scripts, the problem still persists. Could this be an asset issue?